# prevent media scan, set permission or lock the folder and file in android

Tags: android, locking, file-permissions

In my app, me downloading different image and saving inside sdcard under a folder. That file is later used in my app.
What i need is, make this folder only visible to my app. I mean the images should not be available in Android Gallery and other.
Me also saving the sqllite file inside this folder. I also want to restrict any other access  to this sqllite file.
Is there anyway to set permission like anything for folder and file, so that it can only available to my app?
Is there anyway to lock a folder or a file to some specific app?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finlay i found the answer for this
I done it without setting permission, but we can Hide out files from the Media Scanner
Include an empty file named `.nomedia` in your external files directory (note the dot prefix in the filename). This will prevent Android's media scanner from reading your media files and including them in apps like Gallery or Music.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to take a look at the [Environment](http://d.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) class on the dev site
Also look at the API DEMO External storage sample to see how to handle access privately/publicly to the SD

Comment: Private in that context is only organizationally private, and automatically cleaned up if the application is uninstalled.  Nothing actually prevent another application from reading them.

Answer (score 0):

In froyo, you have some secure storage management (called secure containers) but i don't know exactly how it work and if it's directly accessible.
An other solution is to encrypt all your file from your application.
I don't think there is an easy way to set "unix like" permissions, since all app run with the same permission and a rooted user can access anywhere.